# Using INDEX and MATCH with OR condition if both can be true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am selecting certain values from a worksheet with:

```
=INDEX(RGR!E3:RGR!E5;MATCH(1;("FFG"=RGR!B3:RGR!B5) *("BBM"=RGR!E3:RGR!E5)*(((B2=RGR!H3:RGR!H5)+(B2=RGR!C3:RGR!C5)));0);0)
```

The problem can be found in the last part of the code:

```
 *((B2=RGR!H3:RGR!H5)+(B2=RGR!C3:RGR!C5))*
```

If one condition is true the formula gives back a "TRUE", however if both conditions are true (so contain the value for B2) the formula gives a "FALSE" back. I need both conditions to be able to be true and still get a "TRUE" for the whole formula.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MATCH` function has a lookup value of `1` but when both of the `OR` conditions are satisfied (and the other conditions) you will get `2`, hence no match - change the last part so that the conditions will only ever give 1s and zeroes, like this:

`=INDEX(RGR!E3:E5;MATCH(1;("FFG"=RGR!B3:B5)*("BBM"=RGR!E3:E5)*((B2=RGR!H3:H5)+(B2=RGR!C3:C5)>0);0);0)`

Note: You don't need to repeat sheet names within each range, so I removed those

Note 2: won't this formula always return `BBM` or an error?